# How to map raw query fields to class field of entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query:

```
Select p.Name, p.ProductGroupID as GroupID, g.Name as GroupName
FROM Products as p
LEFT JOIN ProductGroups as g
    ON p.ProductGroupID = g.ProductGroupID
```

Can I use 
    dbContext.Database.SqlQuery(query)
to get a list of ProductView, where ProductView is

```
class ProductView
{
    string Name;

    GroupView Group;
}

class GroupView
{
    int id;
    string Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlQuery doesn't support Complex Type

What you should do is:

```
internal class TempResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
}

var tempResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<TempResult>(
    @"Select p.Name, p.ProductGroupID as GroupID, g.Name as GroupName
FROM Products as p
LEFT JOIN ProductGroups as g
    ON p.ProductGroupID = g.ProductGroupID",
    objectParameterList.ToArray()).ToList();

querySearchResult = tempResults.Select(t => new SearchResult
{
    Name = t.Name,
    Group = new GroupView 
        {
            id = t.id,
            Name = t.groupName,
        }
}
```